# How does NHibernate Projections.Max work with an empty table?

Tags: nhibernate

I'm trying to get the maximum value of an integer field in a table.  Specifically, I'm trying to automatically increment the "InvoiceNumber" field when adding a new invoice.  I don't want this to be an autoincrement field in the database, however, since it's controlled by the user -- I'm just trying to take care of the default case.  Right now, I'm using

```
session.CreateCriteria<Invoice>()
        .SetProjection(Projections.Max("InvoiceNumber"))
        .FutureValue<int>();
```

to get the biggest invoice number already in the database.  This works great, except when there are no invoices already in the database.  Then I get a System.ArgumentException: The value "" is not of type "System.Int32" and cannot be used in this generic collection.  Changing to `FutureValue<int?>()` didn't solve the problem.  Is there a way to tell NHibernate to map the empty string to null?  Or is there a better way to accomplish my goal altogether?

The stack trace of the exception (at least the relevant part) is

```
NHibernate.HibernateException: Error executing multi criteria : [SELECT max(this_.[InvoiceNumber]) as y0_ FROM dbo.[tblInvoice] this_;
SELECT this_.ID as ID647_0_, this_.[NHVersion] as column2_647_0_, this_.[Description] as column3_647_0_, this_.[DiscountPercent] as column4_647_0_, this_.[DiscountDateDays] as column5_647_0_, this_.[PaymentDueDateDays] as column6_647_0_, this_.[Notes] as column7_647_0_, this_.[DiscountDateMonths] as column8_647_0_, this_.[PaymentDueDateMonths] as column9_647_0_, this_.[DiscountDatePeriod] as column10_647_0_, this_.[DiscountDateMonthlyDay] as column11_647_0_, this_.[DiscountDateMonthlyDayDay] as column12_647_0_, this_.[DiscountDateMonthlyDayMonth] as column13_647_0_, this_.[DiscountDateMonthlyThe] as column14_647_0_, this_.[DiscountDateMonthlyTheDOW] as column15_647_0_, this_.[DiscountDateMonthlyTheMonth] as column16_647_0_, this_.[DiscountDateMonthlyTheWeek] as column17_647_0_, this_.[PaymentDueDatePeriod] as column18_647_0_, this_.[PaymentDueDateMonthlyDay] as column19_647_0_, this_.[PaymentDueDateMonthlyDayDay] as column20_647_0_, this_.[PaymentDueDateMonthlyDayMonth] as column21_647_0_, this_.[PaymentDueDateMonthlyThe] as column22_647_0_, this_.[PaymentDueDateMonthlyTheDOW] as column23_647_0_, this_.[PaymentDueDateMonthlyTheMonth] as column24_647_0_, this_.[PaymentDueDateMonthlyTheWeek] as column25_647_0_ FROM dbo.[tblTermsCode] this_;
] ---> System.ArgumentException: The value "" is not of type "System.Int32" and cannot be used in this generic collection.
Parameter name: value
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowWrongValueTypeArgumentException(Object value, Type targetType)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.VerifyValueType(Object value)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.System.Collections.IList.Add(Object item)
   at NHibernate.Impl.MultiCriteriaImpl.GetResultsFromDatabase(IList results)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use...`.UniqueValue<int?>();`

NH uses a non-generic IList in their MultiCriteria implementation. Which is used for FutureValue batching. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911577/adding-null-to-a-listbool-cast-as-an-ilist-throwing-an-exception) for why `List<int?>` fails to add null through it's IList implementation. I'm surprised I've never run into this before. Avoid using nullable value types with Future or MultiCriteria.

Comment: FutureValue<int?> has the same problem.  I meant to add that in the question, but forgot to put it in a code span, so the generic got lost--Sorry!

Any other ideas?

Comment: weird, which database are you using? What data type is InvoiceNumber?

Comment: Also, where exactly is this exception thrown? Are you using the non-generic IList anywhere?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server (Specifically 2005, but it happens on 2000 and (I think) 2008 as well).  InvoiceNumber is an int.  I've added the exception to the question, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

With the QueryOver API:

```
Session.QueryOver<T>()
      .Select(Projections.Max<Statistic>(s => s.PeriodStart))
      .SingleOrDefault<object>();
```

if nothing is returned its null, otherwise cast the result as numeric